# Bison -d does not create tab.h

Tags: bison

I have a `.y` file that I trying to use with `bison -d`, but for some reason the `.tab.h` file is not being generated. Any suggestions?

[My bison file in PasteBin:](https://pastebin.com/wqj6sdnh)

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yyerror(const char* err);
%}

%token G
%token INT
%token X
%token Y
%token Z
%token END
%token ZERO
%token EOL

%%

program:    list_of_expr
    ;

list_of_expr:   expr
    |   list_of_expr expr
    ;

expr:       G INT X INT Y INT Z INT EOL
    |   ZERO EOL
    |   END
    ;

%%

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    yyparse();
}
int yyerror(const char* err){
    printf("%s\n", err);
}
```

Comment: What exact command are you using? And what bison version?

Comment: Which version of Bison are you using?  Bison 2.3 on Linux (antique RHEL 5; Bison 2.3 is copyrighted 2006 — though it is also what's shipped with macOS 10.14.1 Mojave) takes your grammar as `parse23.y` and `bison -d parse23.y` generates `parse23.tab.c` and `parse23.tab.h` as you want (on both Linux and macOS).  Which platform and which version of Bison are you using?

Comment: What is the name of your bison file?

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU Bison 3.0.4` (default Ubuntu 18 bison) ~

The `-d` option will only work if your bison grammar file has the `.y` extension, e.g: `my_grammar.y`.

But you can work around it by using `bison --defines=my_tab.h my_grammar.whatever` instead.

EDIT: Your bison grammar file *must* have the `.y` extension.

Comment: Works for me. How are you testing?

Comment: @rici - `bison -d lang.bison`, where `lang.bison` contains the OP's bison file.

Comment: @ricl - Yes, that fixed it too.  :D

Comment: You can use .y++, .ypp, .Y or even .yy if you're using C++. But there has to be a y.

Comment: @rici @Kingsley I am using ubuntu 16.04 with bison 2.1. The exact command I am using is ```bison -d lang.y```. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @farid: that is a very old bison version. Have you considered upgrading? However, I don't see why that version wouldn't produce a header file. It is producing `lang.tab.c`, right?